# Encode strings to image using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, image-processing, piet

Is there any library in Python that encodes data to bitmap patterns and decodes images to data, like the [Piet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esoteric_programming_language#Piet) language?

**Hello World with Piet**

[image: Hello World with Piet]

**UPDATE**

I want to get a string, like *Hello, world* or an URL and encode it as an image, then read this image and decode to a string. Something like a QR code, but using bitmap.

Comment: Why are you trying to close this thread?

Comment: The Piet language does not encode data in images.  The source code of Piet programs is an image, and a Piet interpreter can execute a Piet source image.

Comment: My close vote reason would have been "unclear what you're asking". This question is underspecified. That didn't stop @jsbueno from making a valiant attempt anyway.

Comment: Take a look at [peng](https://github.com/NiklasRosenstein/peng). I think it does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on you plan for `image manipulation` or `image processing` , Python Image Library [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) may be what you are looking for.

Below is a demo code that applies inbuilt filters, derived from [here](http://www.geeks3d.com/20100930/tutorial-first-steps-with-pil-python-imaging-library/#p04)
There are numerous other image processing and pixel manipulation tools available within [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)

**Demo Code**

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFilter

i = Image.open("gImage1.jpg")
im2 = i.filter(ImageFilter.EMBOSS)
im3 = i.filter(ImageFilter.FIND_EDGES)

im2.save("gImage1_EMBOSS.jpg")
im3.save("gImage1_FIND_EDGES.jpg")
```

**Input Image**

[image: Input Image]

**Output Images**
[image: EMBOSS Filter]

[image: FIND EDGES FILTER]

Comment: And how the ability to load images or apply filters actually directs the OP question?

Answer (score 3):

You need an specification of how your data will be represented when used as an image.
That is far more important than an existing piece of code that does the encoding.

On the case of the [Piet Language](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html), it is exactly what happens - this is the "language specification". From it people did build itnerpreters and tools (in a variety of other languages, including a [Python interpreter](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet/Piet_py.txt)).

But if you want to encode arbitrary data to an image, and then decode it back you first have to say how you want to encode it. The most straightforward way is one in which each byte of data is a color channel for one pixel, and a way to determine the exact length of the encoded data, and padding the bottom most image rows.

This would be straightforward to do with Python Imaging Library (Pillow)'s `Image.frombytes` method - though it would hardly result in a pleasing image.

One could also build a Python program to compile a Piet program that just "spills out" the input data back, given arbitrary data - and then, the piet interpreter above could decode the data.

The example bellow will pack a .wav sound file (I just did this at the Python console) as a colorfull image, pre-pending 4 bytes for the data length, and padding the bottom pixels with black.

```
import struct
from PIL import Image
data = open("2600PacManDies.wav", "rb").read()
size  = struct.pack("<I", len(data))
image_side = int(((len(data) + len(size)) / 3.0) ** 0.5) + 1
img = Image.frombytes("RGB", (image_side, image_side) , size + data + b"\x00" * (image_side ** 2 * 3 -  (len(size) + len(data))   ) )
img.save("2600_pacman_dies.png")
```

[image]

(Although as I've used a raw sound data file, one can even discover some patterns in the data looking at the image - the black stripes meaning the silent moments being the most obvious)

Comment: I've edited my question!

Comment: Yes, but still, the other answer does not touch on what you are actually asking, while I attempt to answer it.